# Is this section layout on Area51 intentional?

Tags: bug, design, area-51

I've viewed [Area51.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com) on a wide range of different browsers in the recent past, and every time it looked like this:

[image]

I don't know about you but to me, that vast expanse of emptiness in the center seems... superfluous, at best.

Is this intentional? Why not make the tabs go horizontal, or be two rows? I can't imagine why it would be desirable.

The screenshot was taken using Chrome 47.0.2526.111 on Linux.

Comment: Our sites do not support zooming. Try a Ctrl+0 to reset the zoom level to 100% and the problem will go away.

Comment: @animuson oh, I totally forgot I have Chrome set to render all pages at 90%. That doesn't explain it happening on other browsers, and I've never had zoom affect anything on any other SE site, ever.

Comment: @cat There are things that we technically can't support (as in guarantee they'll work), but we try really hard to not break anyway. Zoom is one of those things. Area51 is a fork from a much older code base, and is more likely to break in 'unsupported' use than other things in the network. Not much has changed there since we launched it, except for bits and bolts to streamline the functionality it serves.

Comment: @TimPost - Kinda related to what you said about A51 being based on an older code base,  but every time I visit there I've been thinking the same thing: Are there any plans to bring the site into a more standardised layout?