# Area 51 layout breaks when zoomed to 90%

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, area-51, google-chrome

I tend to keep my Chrome zoomed to 90% (it gives me more real estate on my work monitor. When I do the layout on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), it breaks (see the image below).

[image]

[image]

`

Comment: SE does not support any zoom other than 100% on its sites. Full stop.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Is this section layout on Area51 intentional?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273047/is-this-section-layout-on-area51-intentional)

Comment: @tac the other way around, since this one here got an answer and official decline stamp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then don't zoom... This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) as far as I know.

As [animuson ♦ said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274424/social-login-buttons-css-on-the-login-register-page-break-when-zoom-less-than-10#comment891801_274424):

> We do not support any zoom levels other than 100%.

And besides that, the site just works, although some content is moved to the bottom.

Comment: Having worked for several web design agencies, etc. If I suggested to a client that "we only support 100% zoom" they'd like laugh in my face....

Comment: You don't have to agree. You can always post a feature request.

Comment: Downvoter: there is no point in downvoting this answer. I don't disagree with the feature being mentioned, but this is the current status. If you care about this feature, please post a feature request.

Comment: No problem @Liam I didn't want to 'accuse' you of doing that, just sharing my POV.